# flutter showPicker not displayed

Tags: flutter, picker

I have a chip widget. I have added an InkWell to have OnTap.
But, when OnTap call the class ShowPickerUnit, the ShowPicker is not displayed.
I have tried stateless, void, widget and I am getting the same result.
I just want the user to be able to select between several values.
I do not understand what I am missing. Please, can you help?
Thank you.

```
Widget chipGoal (){

 return Row(
   children: [
     Wrap(
     // space between chips
     spacing: 10,
     // list of chips
     children: [
     InkWell(
       child: Chip(
         label: Text('Working'),
         avatar: Icon(
         Icons.work,
         color: Colors.red,
       ),
       backgroundColor: Colors.amberAccent,
       padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 5, horizontal: 10),
       ),
       onTap: (){
         ShowPickerUnit();
       },
     ),
     Chip(
     label: Text('Music'),
     avatar: Icon(Icons.headphones),
     backgroundColor: Colors.lightBlueAccent,
     padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 5, horizontal: 10),
     ),
     Chip(
         label: Text('Music'),
         avatar: Icon(Icons.headphones),
         backgroundColor: Colors.lightBlueAccent,
         padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 5, horizontal: 10),
       ),
     ]),
   ],
 );

}
```

```
class ShowPickerUnit extends StatefulWidget {
  const ShowPickerUnit({Key key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _ShowPickerUnitState createState() => _ShowPickerUnitState();
}

class _ShowPickerUnitState extends State<ShowPickerUnit> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
        children: [
          Container(
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
              color: Color(0xffffffff),
              border: Border(
                bottom: BorderSide(
                  color: Color(0xff999999),
                  width: 0.0,
                ),
              ),
            ),
            child: Row(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
              children: [
                CupertinoButton(
                  child: Text('Cancel'),
                  onPressed: () {
                    Navigator.of(context).pop();
                  },
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                    horizontal: 16.0,
                    vertical: 5.0,
                  ),
                ),


                DefaultTextStyle(
                  style: TextStyle(fontSize: 16.0,
                      color: Colors.black,
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                  child: Text('Select what you want'),
                ),

                // Text('Energy Needed', style: TextStyle(fontSize: 12.0, color: Colors.black),
                // ),

                CupertinoButton(
                  child: Text('Confirm'),
                  onPressed: () {

                    setState(() {

                      });
                    Navigator.of(context).pop();
                  },
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                    horizontal: 16.0,
                    vertical: 5.0,
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),

          Container(
            //width: 360,
            height: 250,
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(15.0)),
            ),

            child:
            CupertinoPicker(
              children: [
                Text("India"),
                Text("Usa"),
                Text("Uk"),
                Text("Australia"),
                Text("Africa"),
                Text("New zealand"),
                Text("Germany"),
                Text("Italy"),
                Text("Russia"),
                Text("China"),
              ],
              onSelectedItemChanged: (value){

              },
              itemExtent: 25,
            )
          )]

    );
  }   }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to show it in a dialog, use this `showDialog`

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

const Color darkBlue = Color.fromARGB(255, 18, 32, 47);

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      theme: ThemeData.dark().copyWith(
        scaffoldBackgroundColor: darkBlue,
      ),
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      home: Scaffold(
        body: Center(
          child: MyWidget(),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class MyWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return chipGoal();
  }
}


Widget chipGoal() {
  return Builder(
    builder: (BuildContext context) {
      return Row(
        children: [
          Wrap(
            // space between chips
              spacing: 10,
              // list of chips
              children: [
                InkWell(
                  child: Chip(
                    label: Text('Working'),
                    avatar: Icon(
                      Icons.work,
                      color: Colors.red,
                    ),
                    backgroundColor: Colors.amberAccent,
                    padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 5, horizontal: 10),
                  ),
                  onTap: () {
                    showDialog(
                      context: context,
                      builder: (BuildContext context) {
                        return ShowPickerUnit();
                      },
                    );
                  },
                ),
                Chip(
                  label: Text('Music'),
                  avatar: Icon(Icons.headphones),
                  backgroundColor: Colors.lightBlueAccent,
                  padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 5, horizontal: 10),
                ),
                Chip(
                  label: Text('Music'),
                  avatar: Icon(Icons.headphones),
                  backgroundColor: Colors.lightBlueAccent,
                  padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 5, horizontal: 10),
                ),
              ]),
        ],
      );
    },
  );
}

class ShowPickerUnit extends StatefulWidget {
  const ShowPickerUnit({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _ShowPickerUnitState createState() => _ShowPickerUnitState();
}

class _ShowPickerUnitState extends State<ShowPickerUnit> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end, children: [
      Container(
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          color: Color(0xffffffff),
          border: Border(
            bottom: BorderSide(
              color: Color(0xff999999),
              width: 0.0,
            ),
          ),
        ),
        child: Row(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
          children: [
            CupertinoButton(
              child: Text('Cancel'),
              onPressed: () {
                Navigator.of(context).pop();
              },
              padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                horizontal: 16.0,
                vertical: 5.0,
              ),
            ),

            DefaultTextStyle(
              style: TextStyle(
                  fontSize: 16.0,
                  color: Colors.black,
                  fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
              child: Text('Select what you want'),
            ),

            // Text('Energy Needed', style: TextStyle(fontSize: 12.0, color: Colors.black),
            // ),

            CupertinoButton(
              child: Text('Confirm'),
              onPressed: () {
                setState(() {});
                Navigator.of(context).pop();
              },
              padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                horizontal: 16.0,
                vertical: 5.0,
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
      Container(
        //width: 360,
          height: 250,
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(15.0)),
          ),
          child: CupertinoPicker(
            children: [
              Text("India"),
              Text("Usa"),
              Text("Uk"),
              Text("Australia"),
              Text("Africa"),
              Text("New zealand"),
              Text("Germany"),
              Text("Italy"),
              Text("Russia"),
              Text("China"),
            ],
            onSelectedItemChanged: (value) {},
            itemExtent: 25,
          ))
    ]);
  }
}
```

It shows the dialog when you tap on "Working"

[image]

Comment: Please read [answer] and [edit] your answer to contain an explanation as to why this code would actually solve the problem at hand. Always remember that you're not only solving the problem, but are also educating the OP and any future readers of this post.

Comment: I have tried, but the picker does is not displayed

Comment: It does  for me, check the screenshoot above. You must tap on "Working"

Comment: It does  for me, check the screenshoot above. You must tap on "Working"

Comment: I added the full code, just copy and paste it

Answer (score 0):

Use showModalBottomSheet for data selection

```
Widget chipGoal (){
    
     return Row(
                children: [
                  Wrap(
                    // space between chips
                      spacing: 10,
                      // list of chips
                      children: [
                        InkWell(
                          child: Chip(
                            label: Text('Working'),
                            avatar: Icon(
                              Icons.work,
                              color: Colors.red,
                            ),
                            backgroundColor: Colors.amberAccent,
                            padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 5, horizontal: 10),
                          ),
                          onTap: (){
                            showModalBottomSheet<void>(
                              // context and builder are
                              // required properties in this widget
                              context: context,
                              builder: (BuildContext context) {
                             
                                return ShowPickerUnit();
                              },
                            );
                          },
                        ),
                        Chip(
                          label: Text('Music'),
                          avatar: Icon(Icons.headphones),
                          backgroundColor: Colors.lightBlueAccent,
                          padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 5, horizontal: 10),
                        ),
                        Chip(
                          label: Text('Music'),
                          avatar: Icon(Icons.headphones),
                          backgroundColor: Colors.lightBlueAccent,
                          padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 5, horizontal: 10),
                        ),
                      ]),
                ],
              );
    
    }
    
    
    
    
    class ShowPickerUnit extends StatefulWidget {
      const ShowPickerUnit({Key? key}) : super(key: key);
    
      @override
      _ShowPickerUnitState createState() => _ShowPickerUnitState();
    }
    
    class _ShowPickerUnitState extends State<ShowPickerUnit> {
      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return Column(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
            children: [
              Container(
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  color: Color(0xffffffff),
                  border: Border(
                    bottom: BorderSide(
                      color: Color(0xff999999),
                      width: 0.0,
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
                child: Row(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                  children: [
                    CupertinoButton(
                      child: Text('Cancel'),
                      onPressed: () {
                        Navigator.of(context).pop();
                      },
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                        horizontal: 16.0,
                        vertical: 5.0,
                      ),
                    ),
    
    
                    DefaultTextStyle(
                      style: TextStyle(fontSize: 16.0,
                          color: Colors.black,
                          fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                      child: Text('Select what you want'),
                    ),
    
                    // Text('Energy Needed', style: TextStyle(fontSize: 12.0, color: Colors.black),
                    // ),
    
                    CupertinoButton(
                      child: Text('Confirm'),
                      onPressed: () {
    
                        setState(() {
    
                        });
                        Navigator.of(context).pop();
                      },
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                        horizontal: 16.0,
                        vertical: 5.0,
                      ),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
    
              Expanded(
                child: Container(
                  //width: 360,
                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(15.0)),
                    ),
    
                    child:
                    CupertinoPicker(
                      children: [
                        Text("India"),
                        Text("Usa"),
                        Text("Uk"),
                        Text("Australia"),
                        Text("Africa"),
                        Text("New zealand"),
                        Text("Germany"),
                        Text("Italy"),
                        Text("Russia"),
                        Text("China"),
                      ],
                      onSelectedItemChanged: (value){
    
                      },
                      itemExtent: 25,
                    )
                ),
              )]
    
        );
      }   }
```

Comment: Please read [answer] and [edit] your answer to contain an explanation as to why this code would actually solve the problem at hand. Always remember that you're not only solving the problem, but are also educating the OP and any future readers of this post.

Comment: I have tried, but the picker does is not displayed

Comment: It's working well, I have run it.